# Simplify complex command, put it into a variable

Tags: bash, date, sed, environment-variables

```
date +'%A %B %d' | sed -e 's/\(^\|[^[:digit:]]\+\)0\+\([[:digit:]]\)/\1\2/g
```

I like the output of the above command, which strips leading zeroes off days of the month produced by the `date` command, in the case of numerals less than 10. It's the only way I've thus far found of producing single digit dates from the `date` command's output for the day of the month, which otherwise would be 01, 02, 03, etc.

A couple of questions in this regard. Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing the stated goal of stripping off zeroes? I do know about `date`'s `%e` switch and would like to use it, but with numerals 10 and greater it has the undesirable effect of losing the space between the month name and the date (so, July 2 but July10).

The second question regards the larger intended goal of arriving at such an incantation. I'm putting together a script that will scrape some data from a web page. The best way of locating the target data on the page is by searching on the current date. But the site uses only single digits for the first 9 days of the month, thus the need to strip off leading zeroes. So what's the best way of getting this complex command into a variable so I can call it within my script? Would a variable within a variable be called for here?

**RESOLUTION**
I'll sort of answer my own question here, though it is really input from Renaud Pacalett (below) that enabled me to resolve the matter. His input revealed to me that I'd not understood very well the `man` page, particularly the part where is says "`date` pads numeric fields with zeroes," and below that where it is written "- (hyphen) do not pad the field." Had I understood better those statements, I would have realized that there is no need for the complex `sed` line through which I piped the `date` output in the title of this posting: had I used there `%-d` instead of just `%d` there would have been no leading zeroes in front of numerals less than 10 and so no need to call `sed` (or `tr`, as suggested below by LMC) to strip them off. In light of that, the answer to the second question about putting that incantation into a variable becomes elementary: `var=$(date +'%A %B %-d')` is all that is needed.

I may go ahead and mark Renaud Pacalet's response as the solution since, even though I did not implement all of his suggestions into the latest incarnation of my script, it proved crucial in clarifying key requirements of the task.

Comment: I don't see the problem you describe with `%e` formatter: `date -d '2021-07-10' +'%A %B %e'`, result: `Saturday July 10`. It could be a problem on `sed` part. To put it on a var: `var=$(date -d '2021-07-10' +'%A %B %e')`

Comment: @LMC The %e spec says it leaves a space in place of a zero, so your example would have two spaces between 1 and July on the 1st of July.  But as a matter of fact it seems much simpler to remove duplicate spaces than leading space explicitly.  I'd say `date +'%A %B %e' | perl -n -e 's/  / /g; print $_'`.

Comment: Also `date -d '2021-07-01' +'%A %B %e' | tr -s ' '`

Comment: Ok. It does look like `%e` when used with the pipe to `tr` to remove the extraneous space may be a much more elegant solution than the lengthy `sed` pipe to remove the leading zero. As far as the variable goes I need to search on today's date, so would it be something more like `var=$(date +'%A %B %e' | tr -s ' ')`?

Comment: if you're putting the results into a variable you could cut the subprocess/pipe to `tr` with a paramter substitution, eg: `var=$(date -d '2021-07-01' +'%A %B %e') ; var="${var//  / }"`

Comment: When you say you want to put "it" in a variable, are you talking about storing the command itself, or the result of running the command? If you want to store the command itself, don't use a variable (they're for data, not executable code), use a function instead. If you want to store the *result* of running the command, use `variable=$(command)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `date` utility supports it (the one from GNU coreutils does) you can use:

```
date +'%A %B %-d'
```

The `-` tells date to not pad the numeric field. Demo:

```
$ date -d"2021/07/01" +'%A %B %-d'
Thursday July 1
```

Not sure I understand your second question but if you want to pass this command to a shell script (I do not really understand why you would do that), you can use the `eval` shell command:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo="$(eval "$1")"
echo "$foo"
$ ./foo.sh 'date -d"2021/07/01" +"%A %B %-d"'
Thursday July 1
```

Please pay attention to the double (`"`) and simple (`'`) quotes usage. And of course, you will have to add to this example script what is needed to handle errors, avoid misuses...

Note that many string comparison utilities support one form or another of extended regular expressions. So getting rid of these leading zeros or spaces can be as easy as:

```
grep -E 'Thursday\s+July\s+0*1' foo.txt
```

This would match any line of `foo.txt` containing

```
Thursday<1 or more spaces>July<1 or more spaces><0 or more zeros>1
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd understood the man page to be saying that `%e` and `%-d` were equivalents but that the latter was being deprecated in favor of the former. But testing here reveals they are not equivalent. So it looks like, by using `%-d` instead of `%e` I can dispense with the added code that strips out extraneous space incurred when using `%e` or leading zero when using just `%d`

Comment: The man page of GNU coreutils says that `%e` is the same as `%_d` (underscore), not `%-d` (hyphen). It also says that `-` (hyphen) do not pad the field, `_` (underscore) pad with spaces, `0` (zero) pad with zeros, `+` pad with zeros, and put '+' before future years with >4 digits, `^` use upper case if possible and `#` use opposite case if possible.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I obviously should have read the man page more attentively.

Comment: That or there is just some fundamental unclarity in the `man` page. For example it says regarding `%e` "day of month, space padded." How would I guess from that that it removes the zero `date +%d` otherwise puts in front of numerals less than 10? I obviously did not derive that meaning: it seems to treat 0 as equivalent to space/padding in the case of `date +%B%e` when the day of the month is 1-9.